# D3 Hierarchical Chart X position issue

Tags: d3.js

I have created a D3 Hierarchical chart based on world GDP data. The rectangles represent the countries share of world GDP and the data is organised by continent which is colour coded. The issue is that as the chart updates through the years the X position of the colour continent group changes. I have included two pictures for reference that are screen shots at different years of data in the animation. Does anybody know how this behaviour can be overridden so that the pink group is always in the same X position no matter what the year of data is currently showing?
Screenshot1 [image]

[image]